# Unexpected response code 508

Tags: android, android-volley

Here is a problem.

I couldn't understand this error:

> D/Volley﹕ [1] 3.onErrorResponse: ProfileActivity

Request is finished, but without some data. And once apperead this error:

> [61818] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 508 for http://arcadii.byethost13.com/MyBebe/articles.php

```
private void JSONrequest(){
    // Creating volley request obj
    userDB = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url_article,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i <  10; i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            String description = Html.fromHtml(obj.getString("descriere")).toString();
                            String shortDescription = description.substring(1, 250) + "...";

                            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                            cv.put(UserDataHelper.NAME, obj.getString("nume"));
                            cv.put(UserDataHelper.shortDESCRIPTION, shortDescription);
                            cv.put(UserDataHelper.longDESCRIPTION, description);
                            cv.put(UserDataHelper.PHOTO, "http://mybebe.md/foto/articole/" + obj.getString("foto"));

                            Log.d(obj.getString("descriere"), obj.getString("foto"));

                            boolean db_error = false;

                            Cursor cursor = userDB.query(UserDataHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{
                                            UserDataHelper.AID, UserDataHelper.NAME}, null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null
                            );

                            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(UserDataHelper.NAME));
                                if (name.equals(cv.get(UserDataHelper.NAME))) {
                                    db_error = true;
                                }
                            }
                            cursor.close();

                            if (!db_error) {
                                userDB.insert(UserDataHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    toTakeArticlesFromDB();
}`
```

Here is my logcat (some part, I don't actually know how to paste it to stackoverflow, sorry) and my 508 error was just once, and I don't think that it is the main problem:

```
22249-22249/md.mybebe.mybebe D/memalloc? /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x53067000 size:307200 offset:0
22249-22249/md.mybebe.mybebe I/Adreno200-EGLSUB? <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
22249-22249/md.mybebe.mybebe D/OpenGLRenderer? has fontRender patch
22249-22249/md.mybebe.mybebe D/Volley? [1] 3.onErrorResponse: ProfileActivity
22249-22249/md.mybebe.mybebe D/Volley? [1] Request.finish: 12516 ms: [ ] http://arcadii.byethost13.com/MyBebe/articles.php 0xd2e29c5c NORMAL 1
```

Comment: [HTTP response 508](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) means that the server detected a loop condition. You will need to discuss this with the server maintainers.

Comment: Please post stack trace (logcat), Although HTTP error 508 says "Resource Limit Reached" and this is completely in the server-side and has nothings to do with your Android client. You probably need to contact the server-side team.